# R: Tables with returns [Stargazer example]

Tags: r, dataframe, layout, output, stargazer

I have a dataset containing different stock returns that I want to show in a stargazer table. The problem is that the last row in the dataframe contains NA's in 2 of the 3 columns. Also when I output with stargazer it shows mean, max, min, etc. I only want the actual return value that I have in my dataframe.

Example code:

```
#Creating dataframe
X <- data.frame("Group" = c("Value", "Growth", "HML"), "Excess of riskfree" = c(0.1, 0.2,NA), 
                "Excess of Market" = c(0.2,0.4,NA), "Nominal" = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.01))

#Displaying my dataframe
> X

   Group Excess.of.riskfree Excess.of.Market Nominal
1  Value                0.1              0.2    0.50
2 Growth                0.2              0.4    0.60
3    HML                 NA               NA    0.01

#Setting up stargazer table

stargazer(X, title="Table 1: Returns", align=T, digits=4, out="Table1_Ret.txt", no.space=T, flip=T)

#This gives the following table



Table 1: Returns
=====================================================
Statistic Excess.of.riskfree Excess.of.Market Nominal
-----------------------------------------------------
N                 2                 2            3   
Mean            0.1500            0.3000      0.3700 
St. Dev.        0.0707            0.1414      0.3158 
Min             0.1000            0.2000      0.0100 
Pctl(25)        0.1250            0.2500      0.2550 
Pctl(75)        0.1750            0.3500      0.5500 
Max             0.2000            0.4000      0.6000 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I want the stargazer table to be somewhat equal to the display of my dataframe in R (Group as Rows and variables as column names). And just display the return values, not the statistical approach which seems to be the default layout.

Doesn't necessarily have to be a table from the stargazer package, if there are other (simpler) solution I would be glad to receive that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the summary= FALSE option and set the flip option to F:

```
stargazer(X, summary=F, title="Table 1: Returns", align=T, digits=4, out="Table1_Ret.txt", no.space=T, flip=F)
#Gives you this:

Table 1: Returns
====================================================
  Group  Excess.of.riskfree Excess.of.Market Nominal
----------------------------------------------------
1 Value        0.1000            0.2000      0.5000 
2 Growth       0.2000            0.4000      0.6000 
3  HML                                       0.0100 
----------------------------------------------------
```

Also: stargazer just leaves the NA cells blank. If you want to have it in the table just add it as String:

```
X <- data.frame("Group" = c("Value", "Growth", "HML"), "Excess of riskfree" = c(0.1, 0.2,"NA"), 
            "Excess of Market" = c(0.2,0.4,"NA"), "Nominal" = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.01))

#Then you get this:

Table 1: Returns
====================================================
  Group  Excess.of.riskfree Excess.of.Market Nominal
----------------------------------------------------
1 Value         0.1               0.2        0.5000 
2 Growth        0.2               0.4        0.6000 
3  HML           NA                NA        0.0100 
----------------------------------------------------
```

Have a look at the stargazer documentation [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) for further layout options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Btw, do you know if there is an option for merging tables? Say I had created a dataframe called Y which showed similar returns just for a different sample of stocks, and I wanted to merge with X such that Y showed on the right side in the same table as X. Is this possible?

Comment: Not shure if I understand you correctly. If you want to add the second dataframe as columns to your table you could just combine the two dataframes using `X<- cbind(X,Y)`. Is that what you are aiming to do?

Comment: Well, yes that kinda works too. I sort of want two separate tables yet one if you understand. With Y returns on the right side (split by a vertical line) and X returns on the left side in the same table. Do you know how to add a vertical line to "separate" the X return side and the Y return side of the table? And also how to I get the main title to align in the middle, I thought align = T would do that.